# How to escape inline R command to avoid issue with "while-typing" spelling check

Tags: emacs, sweave, knitr, aquamacs

I have a problem with my text editor Aquamacs Emacs (GNU Emacs 23.4.1) when use it with `\Sexpr` to print inline the output from R functions. The problem results when the R command includes special characters such as **$** and **%**. Even though Latex parses correctly the string, the text editor doesn't escape the special characters. There are then two consequences: the colour of the text changes starting with `\Sexpr` and (most annoyingly) the 'while typing' spelling check is not performed on the remaining of the text. A solution is to wrap `\Sexpr` with `\verb+ +` but then my output results typeset in a different style/font.

Answer (score 3):

I found a temporary fix: I will wrap `\Sexpr` like this: `\verb+\Sexpr{...}+`. Look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134056/how-to-globally-set-verb-font-style-to-match-the-default-document-style) on how to avoid having different typsets.