# How to globally set \verb font style to match the default document style?

Tags: fonts, verbatim

I would like to set the `\verb{}` font so to correspond to the current family and size of my document. That is, the output must be indistinguishable by the rest of the text body whatever style is set as default.

Comment: What do you need `\verb` for, then?

Comment: Good question. I need to cheat on my text editor. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134022/how-to-escape-inline-r-command-to-avoid-issue-with-while-typing-spelling-check).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the default font encoding `OT1` you cannot switch the typewriter font to a normal text font, because of encoding issues (burden of compatiblity). The encoding issues are resolved in font encoding `T1`, for example. Then the font for `\ttfamily` can be changed to use the roman font instead, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% NOT OT1!
\usepackage{lmodern}% Latin Modern fonts,
  % a modern variant of Computer Modern fonts
\let\ttdefault\rmdefault

\begin{document}
  Hello \texttt{World}! \verb|\relax %$&#|
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If you need to inherit the font settings from the context, then `\verbatim@font` can be redefined to do nothing. It is used for `\verb` and environment `verbatim`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% NOT OT1
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\verbatim@font}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Hello \texttt{World}! \verb|\relax %$&#|

  {\sffamily Hello \texttt{World}! \verb|\relax %$&#|}

  {\itshape Hello \texttt{World}! \verb|\relax %$&#|}

  {\bfseries Hello \texttt{World}! \verb|\relax %$&#|}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]